# How can I count the number of items in a grouped query and display Top (x)?

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, count

I'm trying to display the highest count of errors from the results of a group by query

I think I've got the initial group correct but can't figure out the sub query to count the number of errors by module and filter out the highest counts.

```
SELECT Code AS Module
   , ErrCode As ErrorCode
   , Count(ErrCode) AS ErrorCount
   , CAST([Msg-EN] as varchar(max)) as ErrorMsg
FROM ViewAllAlarm
WHERE RiseTime >= DateAdd(Hour, -12, GetDate())
GROUP BY Code, ErrCode,  CAST([Msg-EN] as varchar(max))
Order by Module ASC
```

Result:

```
Module | ErrorCode | ErrorCount | ErrorMsg
-------+-----------+------------+---------
F108   | 194       |        127 | Error2
F108   | 358       |        209 | Error1
F109   | 129       |         11 | Error3
F110   | 129       |        200 | Error3
F110   | 358       |        300 | Error1
F111   | 358       |          2 | Error1
F111   | 129       |          5 | Error3
F112   | 129       |         12 | Error3
F113   | 358       |        200 | Error1
F114   | 194       |        300 | Error2
```

I now need to total the amount of errors (ErrorCount) by module and display the modules with the highest counts (top 5).

This gives 336 errors for F108, 11 for F109, 500 for F110, etc. I want to show the five modules with the highest error counts, which are F110(500), F108(336), F114(300), F113(200), F112(12). Modules F129(11) and F111(7) shall not be shown.

```
Module | ErrorCode | ErrorCount | ErrorMsg
-------+-----------+------------+---------
F108   | 194       |        127 | Error2
F108   | 358       |        209 | Error1
F110   | 129       |        200 | Error3
F110   | 358       |        300 | Error1
F112   | 129       |         12 | Error3
F113   | 358       |        200 | Error1
F114   | 194       |        300 | Error2
```

This is on MS 2016 SQL server.

Comment: dbms name please

Comment: "The number of errors by module"? That would be 336 for module F108 and 11 for F109. You are not grouping by module, though, but by module and error. So what exactly do you want to count? What exactly do you want to show?

Comment: Yes, there are over 15 modules.  This tables shows that there were 127 instances of Error2, and 209 instances of Error1 for F108.  So I need a total of error instances for each module and I only  want to show the 5 modules that have the highest error count total.

Comment: So F108 has a total of 336 errors. If this is among the top 5, you want to show the two rows for F108, one for Error1 and one for Error2. Yes? I've posted an answer.

Comment: Yes, I would like it to list the errors as well, with the count of each error.

Comment: I've edited your request, so as to have an example for what you mean with "modules with the highest counts". It is important to have good examples and explanations in order to get good answers :-) You should also always explain edge cases. In your case you should add a tie, e.g. F115 with another count of 12 errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an `IN` clause to only select the fiove modules with the highest numbers of errors.

```
WITH current AS
(
  SELECT *
  FROM viewallalarm
  WHERE risetime >= DATEADD(HOUR, -12, GETDATE())
)
SELECT
    code AS module
  , errcode As errorcode
  , COUNT(*) AS errorcount
  , MAX(CAST([Msg-EN] as VARCHAR(MAX))) AS errormsg
FROM current
WHERE module IN
(
  SELECT TOP(5) WITH TIES code
  FROM current
  GROUP BY code
  ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
)
GROUP BY code, errcode
ORDER BY module;
```

Or use window functions:

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
  SELECT TOP(5) WITH TIES *
  FROM
  (
    SELECT
        code AS module
      , errcode As errorcode
      , COUNT(*) AS errorcount
      , CAST([Msg-EN] as VARCHAR(MAX)) AS errormsg
      , SUM(COUNT(*)) OVER(PARTITION BY code) AS total
    FROM viewallalarm
    WHERE risetime >= DATEADD(HOUR, -12, GETDATE())
    GROUP BY code, errcode, CAST([Msg-EN] AS VARCHAR(MAX))
  ) summed
  ORDER BY DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY total DESC)
) top_five
ORDER BY module;
```

Comment: This is pretty close though it only returned one module.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: Ah, I see my mistake. Sorry. I'll think of another answer.

Comment: I've updated my answer. One straight-forward query that selects error counts and total counts separately and another using `SUM OVER` again.

Comment: I had to modify the DENSE_RANK line with this ORDER BY DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY total ORDER BY total DESC).  Returns 9 modules though.

Comment: Oh sorry. Yes, I got the `DENSE_RANK` syntax wrong. The `PARTITION BY` must be removed completely. Please see my edit. Now both queries should return the same result, which is the top five modules with ties (i.e. there can also be, say, seven modules having the top five error counts, so those seven would be shown). If, in a situation with ties you only want to show five random modules of those top six, seven, eight, whatever, then remove `WITH TIES` from the first query or change the second query's `DENSE_RANK` line to `ORDER BY DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY total DESC, module)`.

Comment: OK Looks like the second query got me most of the way there. Thanks for all the help!  I had to add the partition back to get it to work the way I needed.  ORDER BY DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY total ORDER BY total)

Comment: Well, this doesn't seem to make sense. With `PARTITION BY total` you only rank within a total sum. And as you rank by this total sum, all rows within must be ranked equal, i.e. 1. Thus you are keeping all rows and could as well remove the `ORDER BY` and `TOP` clauses altogether.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm.  If you just want the modules, then use `group by` and `top`:

```
SELECT TOP (5) Code AS Module, COUNT(*) as cnt
FROM ViewAllAlarm
WHERE RiseTime >= DateAdd(Hour, -12, GetDate())
GROUP BY Code
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC;
```

If you want the errors as well, you could figure something out with window functions, but I think a simple join might be simplest:

```
select vaa.*
from ViewAllAlarm vaa join
     (SELECT TOP (5) Code, COUNT(*) as cnt
      FROM ViewAllAlarm
      WHERE RiseTime >= DateAdd(Hour, -12, GetDate())
      GROUP BY Code
      ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
     ) t5
     on t5.code = vaa.code;
```

Comment: First query works great!  The join query just returns everything.  I would like to have the errors as well, some clarification would be appreciated.

Comment: @NeilB. . . . Clarification on what?  The second query returns the errors as well.

Comment: The 2nd query just returns all the records from the table like a select *

Comment: @NeilB. . . . It should be retrieving all records for the top 5 codes.

Comment: It's returning these headers 'RiseTime Code Name ErrCode Msg-EN
' with all modules

Answer (score 0):

if my sql then  use limit

```
select Code AS Module, count(*) as cnt
FROM ViewAllAlarm
WHERE RiseTime >= DateAdd(Hour, -12, GetDate())
GROUP BY Code
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC limit 5
```